# Error in Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language?

Tags: c++, default-constructor, initialization, built-in-types

The last sentence of §6.3.5.1 from Stroustrup's *The C++ Programming Language* (4th edition here) is:

> A member of an array or a class is default initialized if the array or structure is.

However, [this test](http://codepad.org/UsBchyrW) shows *uninitialized* members of a default initialized object (I also tried with `g++4.7 -std=c++11`)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int i;

    Foo();
};

Foo::Foo() {}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout << "f.i: " << f.i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I must be missing something, but is there an explanation that doesn't mean an error in Stroustrup's affirmation?

---

EDIT: After the answers I understand that the concept of *default initialized* is supposed to include what is called *uninitialized* in other parts of the text (e.g. in §17.3.1). This sounds very unclear to me. In fact, using *uninitialized* to mean anything other than "not explicitly user-initialized" (as is the case in there) is a contradiction: **some things are default initialized and yet uninitialized**. Unless one drops the natural language evidence that X and un-X classify opposite, exclusive sets of things...

Also, an earlier sentence in the same section (§6.3.5.1) reads

> Local variables [...] are not initialized by default unless they are of user-defined types with a default constructor [...]

The contradiction is apparent here again. Accepting both the first and latter statements to be true **implies that there are variables (namely local variables) that are simultaneously *default initialized* and *not initialized by default***.

IMHO this is, at best, a very unclear use of natural language to describe something.

Comment: I think of it as: "default initialization" can be "initialized to an undefined value".  It _is_ initialized, and safe to write to, but undefined to read from.  But yes, the wording is confusing and does contradict itself.

Answer (score 6):

Per § 8.5/7:

> To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   — otherwise, no initialization is performed.

`int` falls in the last point, so it is left uninitialized. If your member had the type, say, `std::string`, it would call the default constructor of `std::string` and you'd have an empty string.

Comment: I think it is unclear at best. From the previous text you would understand a default initialized int to have a value of 0 (this would be the case with a global int variable, for instance). In fact, the previous page reads "Local variables [...] are not initialized by default unless they are of user-defined types with a default constructor". So, this would be a variable that is default-initialized (by the definition you posted) but would not have been initialized by default... doesn't sound very coherent to me

Comment: @ricab, The standard defines default-initialization, value-initialization, and zero-initialization. Uninitialization isn't one of those categories. To your global variable comment, those are zero-initialized (§ 3.6.2/2), which for `int` (and basically everything) means 0. Value-initializing an `int` would also give you 0. However, default-initializing it would not, it would leave it uninitialized. That's the default thing to do when you declare an ordinary local `int` without any initializer. `int` is not a user-defined type, so it is not initialized by default.

Comment: @ricab, The fact that default-initialization can leave things uninitialized might sound weird, but it does make categorizing everything easier.

Comment: @chris got it, your answer together with your first comment answers the original question. Still, it then sounds like the wrong statement is the one I quoted before: "Local variables [...] are not initialized by default unless [...]". Accepting both of these (half-page separated) statements to be true implies that there are variables that are _default initialized_ but _not initialized by default_. It is indeed not what I expected and I still think it unclear.

Comment: @chris, uninitialization isn't one of the categories defined in the standard, but it is a concept used in the book (it is even indexed in the end). Therefore, I think there is a contradiction _in the book_ (didn't say in the standard). Please see my edit for more detailed reasoning